# Colimits of DG-categories and functors between them

Tags: ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, infinity-categories, dg-categories

Suppose I have two diagrams $\{\mathcal{C}_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ and $\{\mathcal{D}_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}$ in the $\infty$-category of DG-categories over a field $k$ with continuous functors (i.e. colimit-preserving functors), indexed by the same small category $\mathcal{I}$. More generally, one can replace DG-categories with presentable stable $\infty$-categories.

Let $F$ be a not necessarily continuous functor between the two diagrams. Let $\{\mathcal{C}_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}^{op}}$ and $\{\mathcal{D}_i\}_{i\in \mathcal{I}^{op}}$ be the opposite diagrams in the $\infty$-category of DG-categories from taking right adjoints. Assume that $F$ is also a well-defined functor between the two opposite diagrams, i.e. the functors $F_i:\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow \mathcal{D}_i$ commute with the right adjoints (in the usual sense).

Let $\text{DGCat}_{\text{cont}}$ denote the category of DG categories with colimits, and morphisms are $k$-linear functors that commute with homotopy colimits.

By 1.3.2 of [Gaitsgory's notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Egaitsgde/GL/textDG.pdf), $\text{colim}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\mathcal{C}_i$ in $\text{DGCat}_{\text{cont}}$ is equivalent to $\lim_{i\in \mathcal{I}^{op}}\mathcal{C}_i$ in DGCat. So the functor $F$ gives a canonical functor $\widetilde{F}: \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}:=\lim_{i\in \mathcal{I}^{op}}\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow \widetilde{\mathcal{D}}:=\lim_{i\in \mathcal{I}^{op}}\mathcal{D}_i$ from the universal property of limits. Let $\text{ev}_i^{\mathcal{C}}: \widetilde{\mathcal{C}}\rightarrow \mathcal{C}_i$ be the tautological evaluation functor, whose left adjoint is denoted by $\text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{C}}$. Set similar notations for $\mathcal{D}_i$. By definition, we have canonical isomorphisms $F_i\circ \text{ev}^{\mathcal{C}}_i\simeq \text{ev}_i^{\mathcal{D}}\circ\widetilde{F}$.

My questions are:

(1) Is it true in general that $\widetilde{F}\circ {\text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{C}}}\simeq \text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{D}}\circ F_i$?

(2) If we assume that each $F_i$ is continuous, does (1) follow easily? In this case, $F$ determines a canonical functor $\widetilde{F}':\text{colim}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow \text{colim}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\mathcal{D}_i$ from the universal property of colimits. The question is whether this agrees with $\widetilde{F}$ under the natural equivalence $\text{colim}_{i\in \mathcal{I}}\mathcal{C}_i\rightarrow \widetilde{C}$ (and also for the diagram $\{\mathcal{D}_i\}_{i\in I}$) induced by $\text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{C}}$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to (2) is yes, by a nice result of Gaitsgory plus an easy categorical argument. To spell it out, the situation of the OP is the following, where functors going down are $ev_i$ and functors going up are their left adjoints $ins_i$:

$$ \begin{array}{rrrr}
\widetilde{D} & \stackrel{\widetilde{F}}{\leftrightarrows} & \widetilde{C}\\\
\uparrow \downarrow  &          & \uparrow \downarrow  \\\
D_i & \stackrel{F_i}{\leftrightarrows} & C_i
\end{array}
$$

Here we know $\widetilde{F}$ has a left adjoint by Lemma 2.6.4 in Chapter 1 of [the book by Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum](https://math.uchicago.edu/%7Enick/writing/Vol1.pdf), which also tells us that the two ways of going around by right adjoints are isomorphic. Following their notation, let $F^R$ denote the right adjoint of $\widetilde{F}$ and $F_i^R$ denote the right adjoint of $F_i$). Lemma 2.6.4 points out that $\text{ev}^{\mathcal{C}}_i \circ F^R \simeq F_i^R \circ \text{ev}_i^{\mathcal{D}}$ as functors from $\widetilde{D}$ to $C_i$. Be warned that Gaitsgory and Rozenblyum start with $\Phi: D\to C$ rather than $F: C\to D$, so I've had to swap $C$s and $D$s from their notation.

Now, when you have a square of adjunctions, and the two ways of going around by right adjoints commute, [then the two ways of going around by left adjoints also commute](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3027355/commuting-right-adjoints-implies-commuting-left-adjoints). This argument works just as well in an $\infty$-categorical context, a DG-category context, or a 1-categorical context, and in our case proves that $\widetilde{F}\circ {\text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{C}}}\simeq \text{ins}_i^{\mathcal{D}}\circ F_i$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answers my question (2).